# Get certain childrens with JDOM

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I currently have this line of code :

```
org.jdom2.Element typeContent = root.getChildren().get(objTypeIndex);
```

This was working fine until you added children with other names. Then it started to bug and change the data in the wrong child.
If I got index 1 it would get the first  earlier.
but with new children it will get the  instead with current line of code.
That not what I want to do.

Is there anyway I can get all children by name ?

If I have root children like

```
<insert-data></insert-data>
<insert-data></insert-data>
<insert-data></insert-data>
```

and then

```
<type></type>
<type></type>
<type></type>
<type></type>
```

And I only wanna get the  from the root?
How can I do that with JDOM.

Ive tried :

```
org.jdom2.Element typeContent = (Element) root.getChildren("type").get(
                objTypeIndex);
```

but it cast exception : `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 19 Size: 19`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the API (http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#getChildren(java.lang.String)), how to be able to obtain children by name.

Comment: Ive done that before I posted and its casting exception

Comment: Yes, because you statically access a given index without knowing if this index is valid.

Comment: org.jdom2.Element typeContent = root.getChildren().get(objTypeIndex); This one is working but edit on wrong place atm. but when I add "type" in my getchildren it gives exception. So nothing wrong with the index I think right? the index is 19. And I have 19 <type>

Comment: oh yes. it starts counting from 0 not from 1. Thats it.